# Writing "Wav" file in GNU Radio 3.9.0

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio, audio

I need to burn an audio file received from a computer sound card. But in the new version of the gnu radio, I found that the "Wav File Sink" and "Wav File Source" blocks were gone. Tell me, how can I write to the WAV file now?

[image]

I am using the graph as in the picture, but the recorded file cannot be opened by the audio player: I get the error "The file cannot be played. The file format may not be supported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is damaged". In this case, in the "file sink" block, I manually wrote the file extension ".wav"

Comment: They're not gone. How did you install GNU Radio? You probably are missing the libsndfile dependency.

Comment: Downloaded from here http://www.gcndevelopment.com/gnuradio/downloads.htm.  Perhaps you `re right.  How to add this dependency?

Comment: What error occurs?

Comment: "The file cannot be played. The file format may not be supported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is damaged."

Comment: @Антон you can't just write the raw data to a file (using a File Sink), attach .wav to the filename, and expect it to be a valid wav file. That's not how file formats work.

Comment: I already figured it out.  Can you tell me how I can add an audio block for recording?  I don't have it among the blocks

Answer (score 2):

Although you probably figured out the solution until now, in order to have the `Wav File Source/ Sink` blocks available you need to make sure to install the `libsndfile1-dev` dependency.

You should better run:
`sudo apt install pybind11-dev python3-matplotlib libsndfile1-dev \ pygccxml pyqtgraph libsoapysdr-dev soapysdr-tools`
, in order to install all the dependencies for the 3.9 version as mentioned [here](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/UbuntuInstall#Focal_Fossa_.2820.04.29_through_Hirsute_Hippo_.2821.04.29).

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Nice first answer!

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to do this on Windows